# include the names in the plot in python

Tags: python, plot

I have made the attached plot using the following piece of code. and I am trying to name different part of that as it is in the code but the names (B1, S and B2, for the first half, exactly middle part and the 2nd half respectively) are not included in the plot.

```
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(9, 4.5))
xmax = vc.shape[0]
for isample, sample in enumerate(sampleinfo):
    ax.plot(vc[:, isample], color=sample[3], label="%s\n$n=%d$" % (sample[2], ws[isample]))
ax.set_xlim([0, 2*xmax/3])
ax.set_xticklabels(["B1", "S" "B2"], ha="center", weight="bold")
ax.get_xticklabels()[0].set_horizontalalignment("center")
ax.get_xticklabels()[-1].set_horizontalalignment("center")
ax.set_ylabel("Aount)")
```

here is the figure I got using the code:

[image]

do you know how to included the names in the plot?

I want a plot like this:

[image]

Comment: How would you like the graph to look?

Comment: the question is eddited.

Answer (score 0):

Use the size of the domain to determine the quarter, half, and three-quarters mark on the x-axis. Pass these locations to `ax.set_xticks` and label them subsequently using `set_xticklabels`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(9, 4.5))
x = [1,2,4]
y = [4,5,6]
ax.plot(x,y)

xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
domain = xmax - xmin

tick_locations = (xmin + domain/4,xmin+domain/2, xmax-domain/4)
ax.set_xticks(tick_locations)
ax.set_xticklabels(["B1", "S", "B2"], ha='center')

ax.set_ylabel("Amount)")

plt.show()
```

[image]